# matlab: extend matrices after union of their related time stamp

Tags: matlab, timestamp, time-series

I have to matrices, A(n,2) and B(m,2). Both of them show voltage of a signal on defined moment of time. In both of these matrices, first column shows **time** and 2nd column shows **voltage** on that moment of time.
For ease of demonstration I showed them in horizontal form in below picture: [image]

I'm going to compare these signals in my tests so I need to make their timestamps like each other. 
So time stamps should be union of time stamps of A and B, i.e. *[1 2 3 4 5 10 11 13 15 16]*

Using this new timestamps, I need to extend A and B such that when there is a sample and that moment, its values must be reflected otherwise voltage at that time moment should be considered **0** as depicted below:
[image]

I my real application, I have thousands of matrices like A and B, so I used `unique` over matrix which consisted of all timestamps so that way I will have all timestamps. I my previous problem I used `interp1` to handle situation of missing timestamps and it would interpolate sample which were missing however currently I need to put **0** for voltage value whenever a sample is missing.
I want to know how can I handle the case?

**Input:**

```
A= [1   2   3   4   10  11  15; 1.01    1.02    1.03    1.04    1.10    1.11    1.15]


B= [1   3   5   10  13  16;2.01 2.03    2.05    2.10    2.13    2.16]
```

**Output:**

```
Ax  = [1    2   3   4   5   10  11  13  15  16; 1.01    1.02    1.03    1.04    0   1.10    1.11    0   1.15    0]
Bx = [1  2  3   4   5   10  11  13  15  16;2.01 0   2.03    0   2.05    2.10    0   2.13    0   2.16]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way. This assumes that the first row of each matrix doesn't have repeated values, and makes use of the fact that missing values when extending a matrix are automatically set to `0`.

```
u = unique([A(1,:) B(1,:)]);
Ax = u;
Ax(2, ismember(u, A(1,:))) = A(2,:);
Bx = u;
Bx(2, ismember(u, B(1,:))) = B(2,:);
```

Comment: I did knew that `ismember` would help me but I didn't know the right syntax and trick! your snippet is very efficient and  very simple.